# How to load more than one ViewController when using TabBarController?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a TabBarController with 7 Custom ViewControllers and what i am trying to do is have the TabBarController on startup load the first ViewController in its array as well as a ViewController in one of the other tabs.

As far as i understand it the viewDidLoad method for the ViewController's is only called for that tab when it is first selected. Is there a way to force the TabBarController to call a ViewController viewDidLoad method even if its not active?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reference the ViewController view:

```
[myViewController view]
```

If myViewController's view is nil, then it will be loaded.

Note that even if this approach is working, your app will be affected by the view loading/unloading mechanism which is controlled by the internal run loop logic and not by your app, while the view controller "internal logic" should be initialized by the initWithNib: method which is completely under your control. But this is just a suggestion to avoid strange bugs, anyway the solution proposed is working.

Comment: That works great! So you would suggest using the above method if say one of my tabs is an update tab that i want to run on app startup, although i want the first tab to be the one that gets displayed?

Comment: Yes, you can do this if you want. You can pre-load all views by simply referencing them. Anyway I recommend you to don't mix the view (GUI stuff) with controller logic, so don't abuse with this approach. It may be cause of weird issues, e.g. if you rely on some UITextField in the view and then you set its "text" property before loading the view, you will be infact setting a value to a nil object: so nothing will be set and the runtime will never comply for this.

Answer (score 0):

This technique seems to work pretty good. I have an app with a UITabBarController at the bottom with 5 buttons in it. When the user clicks the 3rd button, the viewDidLoad for that view took 5 seconds to do stuff so I used this technique to cause its viewDidLoad to get called when the app starts. I don't want the 3rd view to be displayed; just to be initialized so it shows up instantly when clicked.

I had to subclass the UITabBarController to something like FoohBarController, then in it's viewDidLoad I made a background thread do this:

```
{
  // get a pointer to the 3rd item in the tab bar (0 based)
  UINavigationController *navcon = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]; 

  // get a pointer to the viewController I want to init
  CalendarViewController *calendar = [navcon.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

  // Just ask for the view. This will force the view to load and to initialize
  UIView *v = calendar.view;
  v = nil;    // to remove a compiler warning
}
```